# Query in Supabase with two eq() returning wrong data

Tags: supabase, rtk-query

I have the table "asignaturas" (subjects), table "cursos" (courses) and the table "grupos_especialidades" (specialties_group). Then I have a join table to include the three of them. Here you have a screenshot of one of the subjects linked to two different courses and a different group of instruments in each course:

When I do this query:

```js
let query = supabase
      .from("asignaturas")
      .select(`*,
        curso: cursos!inner ( id ),
        grupos_especialidades!inner ( id )
      `)
      .eq("curso.id", 5)
      .eq("grupos_especialidades.id", 1);
    
    const { data, error } = await query;
    
    return { data, error };
```

I shouldn't receive any output because with the course_id: 5 and group_id: 1 there is no row that has both conditions. However I am obtaining the asignatura_id: 7 that you see in the screenshot.

[image: Rows of the subject that is being returned]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the full details of how each tables are related to each other, but it seems like the `asignaturas` contains all the information you need to perform this query. Just keep it simple and do this.

```js
const { data, error } = await  supabase
      .from("asignaturas")
      .select()
      .eq("curso_id", 5)
      .eq("grupo_id", 1);
```